Recovering Examples Tanner Code Constructions
I've been trying to understand how the construction of Tanner codes works. The only example that I've found is in Tanner's original paper. However, I can't recover the claimed code parameters, and I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the construction or just can't find an appropriate numbering of the vertices. Can someone fill in the blanks?
What I think I'm doing with the Tanner code construction, as applied to the example:

We start with a complete graph on 8 vertices. I write down the incidence matrix, which is an $8\times 28$ matrix such that each column has weight 2 and each row has weight 7. (A row is associated with a vertex of the graph, telling us which edges attach to it.)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
   & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
   & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
   & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For each 1 in the incidence matrix, I pick a value 1 to 7 such that no number is repeated in each row. (There are many valid assignments, which can yield different code parameters.) For example:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 7 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7
   & 6 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1
   & 0 & 0 & 7 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0
   & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0
   & 0 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I replace each number with the corresponding column of the Hamming code's parity check matrix.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The resulting matrix is a $24\times 28$ binary matrix constituting the parity check matrix of my new code. In the above case, the first column becomes
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \end{array}\right)
$$
followed by 18 0s (the whole thing is rather large!)

The example constructed in this way gives me a $[28,5]$ code, where Tanner's paper claims a $[28,9]$ code. Have I misunderstood something, or have I simply not found the appropriate assignment of numbers in my second step?
